# Can I make the caret blink again after it stopped blinking?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Normal behaviour for the caret in Windows 10 seems to be that as soon as a caret-capable control gets focus the caret will blink for about 5 seconds and then go solid (non-blinking). Whenever the left or right arrow keys are pressed it will move the caret and then it will start to blink again for the 5 second period, etc.

I cannot get the same behaviour on my custom control. Creation, displaying, moving and destruction of the caret seems to work fine but it will only blink for the 5 second duration after getting focus and perhaps one more time upon moving it with the arrow keys but never after that again. It stays solid (non-blinking) every time I move the caret with the arrow keys.

It will blink again if the control looses focus and regains it.

I noticed on another 3rd party control's source code that the authors used the [`SetCaretBlinkTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcaretblinktime) api call and I wonder if that was to get the desired effect but `SetCaretBlinkTime's` documenation encourages developers to only use it when actually wanting to set the blink rate similar to what the Keyboard Control Panel Applet does.

My custom control:

```
const
CCharWidth = 8;
CWidth = 200;
CInsideMargin = 2;
CCharsPerLine = (CWidth - (CInsideMargin * 2)) div CCharWidth;

type
TEditPane = class(TCustomControl)
private
  FCaretPosX : Integer;

  procedure SetCaretPosition(AXPos : Integer);

  procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
  procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
  procedure WMKillFocus(var Message: TWMKillFocus); message WM_KILLFOCUS;
  procedure WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
  procedure WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus); message WM_SETFOCUS;
protected
  procedure Paint; override;
public
end;

implementation

procedure TEditPane.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWindow;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Width,Height));
end;

procedure TEditPane.SetCaretPosition(AXPos : Integer);
begin
  If AXPos < CInsideMargin then
    AXPos := CInsideMargin;

  If AXPos > CInsideMargin + (CCharsPerLine * CCharWidth) then
    AXPos := CInsideMargin + (CCharsPerLine * CCharWidth);

  FCaretPosX := AXPos;
  SetCaretPos(FCaretPosX,CInsideMargin);
end;

procedure TEditPane.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTARROWS;
end;

procedure TEditPane.WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown);
begin
  inherited;
  Case Message.CharCode of
    VK_LEFT :
      SetCaretPosition(FCaretPosX - CCharWidth);
    VK_RIGHT :
      SetCaretPosition(FCaretPosX + CCharWidth);
  end;
end;

procedure TEditPane.WMKillFocus(var Message: TWMKillFocus);
begin
  inherited;
  HideCaret(Handle);
  DestroyCaret;
end;

procedure TEditPane.WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown);
begin
  inherited;
  SetFocus;
end;

procedure TEditPane.WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus);
begin
  inherited;
  CreateCaret(Handle,0,1,13);
  SetCaretPosition(CInsideMargin);
  ShowCaret(Handle);
end;
```

Comment: What happens if you: Hide, SetPos, Show when processing keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blinking is resumed after you show the caret. So you can

```
HideCaret(Handle); { assuming that show counter is 1 }
ShowCaret(Handle);
```

or repeat your code form `WMSetFocus`

```
CreateCaret(Handle,0,1,13);
SetCaretPosition(CInsideMargin);
ShowCaret(Handle);
```

Blinking also resumes after `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` because it implicitly hides and shows caret if visible but it is side-effect and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: The `HideCaret/ShowCaret` solution works well, thanks.